# How to attach an action call to a submit button in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a page where a deactivated user account can be activated - but before they can be activated, they need to be assigned a new password. Currently I have two buttons to perform these actions:

At the end of the 'add password' form there is this button:

```
<%= f.submit %>
```

A little further on the page there is this button, which sets the status of the user to 'active':

```
<%= standard_button 'Activate user', update_status_user_path(@user),
:method => :patch %>
```

If possible, I'd like add the functionality of the second button to the submit button.

I don't fully grasp the magic behind forms and their buttons, so I am wondering whether this is possible and if so, how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think of a button as a mini form. View the [docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to) to get more information about the button_to rails method.

In your form_for, there will be a url which specifies where the form is posting to. In that controller method, you can include the logic to update the user's status to 'active'. Something like

```
def some_method
  user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  user.update_attribute(:status, "active")
end
```

Comment: The form currently posts to a password change method that is used by many other pages too. So if possible, I'd rather avoid making changes in that particular method. It's not possible to have a button do two seperate things - submitting a form, and calling some action?

Comment: A form can only post to one action, so that action will have to handle updating the user status. You could use javascript to update the user status but that would not be advisable. Another option would be to include a hidden field or a data attribute in the form. The action could then check for the hidden field and update the user status only if the hidden field is present. Or the form action could check where the request is coming from and update the user status only if the request is from a certain page.